# How come I can use ' and not " in function that requires a byte type

Tags: go

Why scrolling through some posts I saw someone using the function `reader.ReadString('\n')` I noticed the post used `'` instead of `"`. What's going on here? And can this be applied anywhere else besides this situation?

Comment: you use `''` for single chars and `""` for arbitrary-length strings. That's what's going on.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes `''` denote [rune literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals) while double-quotes `""` and backticks ``` `` ``` denote [string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals). [`bufio.Reader.ReadString`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) takes a `byte`, which can be represented by a single-byte rune literal such as `'\n'`.